# IOS Swift beginner

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, swift2

In a screen, view-scrollview-contentview, there are a lot of textfields in the contentview so I use a scrollview to make them in one screen.Now the problem is I could not click or type in the textfield because I know the scrollview has covered the contentview. But I want to type in the textfield and be able to scroll the screen as well. I tried to see a lot of answers here but could not figure out the correct solution.
Both the scrollview and contentview are user interaction enabled, switch on/off the "delays content touches"/"Cancellable content touches" in scrollview but doesn't work.
Appreciate any help.

Comment: Is the textfield placing on the scrollview?

Comment: you should put textfield in scrollview, not content view.

Comment: If I put in scrollview, how to scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create two notifications (once when the keyboard appears and other when it dissapear) on the **viewDidLoad** :

```
  //Notifications for keyBoard when appears.
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object:  nil)
```

then call the function which calculates the padding and make an scroll.

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification){
        var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
        var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
        keyboardFrame = self.view.convertRect(keyboardFrame, fromView: nil)

        var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = self.scrollview.contentInset
        contentInset.bottom = keyboardFrame.size.height
        self.scrollview.contentInset = contentInset
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification){
        var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        self.scrollview.contentInset = contentInset
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried above codes but still doesn't work. Are there other steps I need to do?

Comment: Did you create the outlet of scrollView and change its name in `self.scrollview`? I've edited the answer, look the new structure of the notifications.

Comment: I hold the control and pull the scrollview to the .swift connect to @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!    And change the self.scrollview to self.scrollView, is it correct?

Comment: Yeah that's correct

Comment: Oh it works now!!! Thank you so so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use TPKeyboardAvoiding for auto manage scroll when click on textfield.

https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Make TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView object and add textfield into this scrollview so it will work fine.

In storyboard use class name "TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView" in identity inspector and bind it to work well.

Comment: Hi, I downloaded it and put the file TPKeyboardAvoiding into my project. Also set the scrollview class as TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView. But it still doesn't work, and got the warning "Unknown class TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView in Interface Builder file." Are there any other steps I need to do?

Comment: Need to import it in bridge file.

Comment: I am sorry I am a beginner, could you please tell me how to import it in bridge file?