# How do I use #selector?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

How do I convert these statements to use the `#selector` statement.
The statements work fine but gives warnings in Xcode, which I dislike.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

Comment: just click on the warning and press enter

Comment: Or 10 seconds of search: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38841125/1187415.

Comment: Call them `#selector(keyboardWillShow)` and `#selector(keyboardWillHide)`.

Comment: @matt: How is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658334/how-do-i-resolve-ambiguous-use-of-compile-error-with-swift-selector-syntax?

Comment: @MartinR The answer tells everything the OP could possibly want to know about this syntax.

Comment: @matt: But the *question* is different. "Duplicate" means: "This question has been asked before ..." – But never mind, this question isn't worth arguing about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147831/syntax-selector-swift-2-2 (Swift 2), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825327/swift-3-nsnotificationcenter-keyboardwillshow-hide (Swift 3).

Comment: @MartinR That is a common misconception, but it's wrong. The question is _never_ going to be identically the same. "Duplicate" means the question has an answer that fully addresses the OP's question (as the SO notice says).

Comment: @matt: That is not how I understand the (top voted) answer to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266244/can-a-question-be-a-duplicate-if-its-totally-different. "How do I convert Selector() to #selector" is not the same question as "How do I resolve ambiguous use of  #selector?"

Comment: I don't have many experience with developing for ios yet, so I didn't know this was the same in other #selector statements. Thank for helping it does work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift 3, it looks like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

Comment: thanks, so in my case this was the solution:         NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)